# downloading a .csv file in PHP stops my other PHP code

Tags: php, csv

With PHP I'm opening a .csv file, I'm adding som rows in it then I'm downloading the new .csv file.

the code I'm using is:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


$file = fopen("csv.csv","r");
$list = array();

while(! feof($file))
  {
      $list[] = (fgetcsv($file));
  }
fclose($file);

$list[] = array('name5', 'town5');
$list[] = array('name6', 'town6');

$list = array_filter($list);
outputCSV($list);

function outputCSV($list) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

My issue is the other PHP code in the page don't generate, and only the .csv file is being download.

for exemple if I'm adding:

```
echo "test";
```

it won't be display and only csv.csv will be downloaded

How can I display my "echo test;" ?

Comment: do error_log("test") and look into your php log file, you'll see your test there.

Comment: You have set header `Content-Disposition:` to `attachment` so whatever you write will be printed in attachment. 
If you want to print something and downloading file also than create another PHP file which will generate CSV file and link that file to other page where your `echo` is.

Comment: You cannot use the same page to push a file to a user AND print output.  You'll need to use differents pages or other mechanisms for that.

Answer (score 0):

With the headers you are telling the browser to download a CSV, there is no where to output your echo.

You could make a page with the information you want to show that has an iframe with the csv code in it.